# Safari column rendering bug

Tags: css, safari, multiple-columns

Safari 7 and 8 seem to render the title of the elements in the right column of my site (https://unindented.org/) incorrectly:

[image: Titles in right column rendered incorrectly]

I'm just doing the following on the container:

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
   -moz-column-width: auto;
        column-width: auto;
```

Is there a workaround for this bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two options here:

1. Remove the `overflow: hidden` from your `header` element.
2. Remove the `border-radius` property from your `header`

I wish I could tell you *why* these will work.  But Safari's implementation of webkit is almost as bad as IE at times.

Comment: This is insanity!